# Update an item view in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` which is getting list of favourite and Unfavourite item. There is a Star icon in the item onClick of which i am calling an API which return added to favorite or removed from favourite. 
Now i am Trying to update star icon in the `RecyclerView`

`OnSuccess` of my task i am updating my list with this code

```
adapterParcel.notifyItemChanged(position, modelParcelsArrayList);
                        adapterParcel.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In my Adapter `onBindViewHolder` i am trying to update view by this code

```
if (singleModelParcels.is_favouriteParcel()) {
                itemListHolder.rpl_iv_favorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_fav_yellow);
            } else {
                itemListHolder.rpl_iv_favorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_fav_white);
            }
```

I am unable to figure out what should i do to update View of that item.

Answer (score 2):

The `notifyDataSetChanged` method refreshes the items in the recyclerView adapter i.e . they again go through the `onBindViewHolder` state.

if you have modified you object properly to hold the fav value (true/false)
then inside the `onBindViewHolder` you can simple access that value an set the view, something like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
   Object object = objectList.get(position);
   if (object.isFav()){
     holder.favIcon.highlight();
   }else{
     holder.favIcon.unhighlight();
   }
}
```

So all you have to do is call the notifyDataSetChanged method on the adapter and the code inside the `onBindViewHolder` mthod will handle it for you!

Check a similar project created by me, [here](https://github.com/shahsurajk/ChatTest)

Comment: see, you are calling the notifyItemChanged method and then again the notifydatachanged method too. So technically you dont need them, try this, update the value in your model inside the list (the list you have bind with the RV adapter) and once you have changed the value in the list then just call the `notifyDataSetChaged`. but remember you have to modify the item in your list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same by using notifyItemChanged but in that scenario you will need to update the entity at that position which would refresh the view in adapter.

Comment: i am calling that adapterParcel.notifyItemChanged(position, modelParcelsArrayList);

Comment: But are you modifying the entity in modelParcelArraylist for that position which would reflect the view in you adpater

Comment: I am trying to modify it in my adapter with view using boolean.

Comment: And that boolean is getting updated through which flow?